# GCP cloud function to kafka ( in compute engine ) with vpc access connector

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, google-cloud-functions, google-vpc

I've been trying to this pipeline.

Cloud Function(kafka-python) -> (vpc access connector) -> Kafka (Compute Engine)
( Internal IP )

But It doesn't work.

in python code =>

initialize and connect producer doesn't error  (success)

```
producer=KafkaProducer(acks=0, compression_type='gzip', bootstrap_servers=['kafka-internalIP:9092'], value_serializer=lambda x: dumps(x).encode('utf-8') )
```

but if I try to send there is "timeout"

```
producer.send( ... )
```

My kafka (server.properties)

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092  
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://kakaserverInternalIP:9092
```

I don't know why there is a timeout. I've tried same code in localserver and another server, it works.

I think vpc access connector and  "advertied.listeners" are problems but I don't understand :(...

I've tried change "advertised.listeners" PLAINTEXT://:9092 and externalIP but it doesn't work.

and I checked network by "IFTOP"

and there are "myserver:9092 <=> vpc-connector:..."

But... timeout :(

Comment: 2 things to check: firstly, are the Serverless VPC connector and the Kafka VM in the same VPC? Then, did you check the firewall rules? Allow ingress on the port 9092 on your kafka VM from your serverless VPC connector range

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes, when I make VPC connector, the firewall rules were auto updated ( all port) and yes same vpc.,